# php access modifiers, access attribute without being declared in the class

Tags: php

someone could tell me why this code works

```
class Perro {

}

$objPerro = new Perro();
$objPerro->nombre = 'Pluto';
echo $objPerro->nombre;
```

I'm looking in the documentation and can not find references, the code runs perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are a converting a single variable into object and adding a key to this object. There is nothing special to declare in documentation.